# What is the correct way to publish a MVC4 WebAPI application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have completed a WebAPI application on my local machine. But when I published it onto the testing server, there is no `~\Api` folder in the site root folder.

Then I select every files under that folder, all of which are ApiControllers and in the properties, I set `Build Action` to be `Compile` and `Copy to Output Directory` into `Copy if newer`, thinking that must be the correct way.

However, I found all the ApiControllers were uploaded into `~/bin/Api`. Therefore, every Api call returns a `404 Not Found`.

What is the correct way to set up the publish settings?

Comment: Right after publicing your Web API application, did you try to run before copying?

Comment: It runs with no problem on the local machine.

Comment: I meant did you tried RIGH AFTER publishing and what is problem?

Comment: My ajax calls returns 404 not found error for all api paths. Should I change the default `Build Action` for those `Api/{xxx}Controller.cs` files?

Comment: are you sure you routed `/Api` instead of `/api` ?